# How do I log into django? (Rant warning)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given:

1. A default-configured django service, and;
2. A default-configured django rest framework:

How do I log in?

By "default-configured", I mean that I followed the suggested tutorials of both websites.

However, neither django nor the django rest framework discusses how to use the authentication system as a *user*.   They often seem to discuss authentication from the point of view of the python code running within the django framework.

Where can I read concise, clear documentation that tells me how the user requests the website with correct authentication?

I know that my DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES in 'REST_FRAMEWORK' is set to: rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly

Which implies that I am probably using whatever authentication is set in the django webservice by default.

And I know that my django instance has "Authenticationmiddleware" and "CsrfViewMiddleware" and the like, whatever they mean. (Ok, CSRF is easy to google, but that's besides the point)

The relevant django documentation *seems* to be https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/

However, that doesn't tell me how to actually log INTO the website so that I can POST some data.

Where can I find simple, concise instructions that tell me how to:

1. GET some data as a particular user, and.
2. POST some data as a particular user.

In the mean time, I will continue perusing the documentation.

So far I have attempted to do:

1. Obtain the csrf cookie by using GET /api-auth/login/
2. Perform the login by using POST /api-auth/login/ and providing the cookie obtained in the previous step.

However, Django still detects forgery.

Comment: What's the use case? Your talking about Django and Rest Framework, which are two different things.

Comment: They are two different types of authentication (the former is persistant and the latter isn't) for two different forms of communication with your general service so you have two separate authentication approaches. For the django service, you need to create templates that the views of django auth will use (or use the django admin depending on your auth), for django-rest, see here: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony: Yes, but sadly while that site does get a bit closer to providing a real example, it neglects to point out how such a token should be obtained.

Comment: btoueg: Ok, use case: "I want to post JSON formatted data using curl".  Or ruby. Whatever, but using the default authentication system.

Comment: Did you actually write any authentication code on the server side? Django will not do that for you (at least not vanilla Django). And when you do it, then it is as simple as calling an appropriate route with credentials.

Comment: @freakish: No, I didn't, actually.  However, django-rest-framework does provide a login page at /api-auth/login/

Comment: @Arafangion Question: are those two web apps using the same domain?

Comment: @mariodev: Yep, both running at localhost:8000

Comment: It appears that the confusion was that the djangoo-rest-framework provided a login page, but the authentication on that page is different from the rest, which turn out to be basic authentication, except I didn't want basic authentication.

Comment: @Arafangion So.. have you solved your issue then?.. I don't quite understand what do you have a problem with.. if both apps using the same domain, then they share both cookies (session, csrf), which means you just need `SessionAuthentication` and send the csrf key over with ajax.

Comment: mariodev: Yes, I have.  I should update my answer below, actually - I hadn't realised that the various pages that django and the django-rest-framework use different authentication to that of the django-rest-framework's api. (Ie, posting json-formatted data could use BASIC auth, even though it's own login page could not and required csrf tokens.).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

django-rest-framework provides a login page for you if you follow the documentation at http://django-rest-framework.org/

django by default, at least in version 1.5, uses CSRF tokens for security.

In order to login, you need to:

1. Obtain the cookies by visiting the login page, at /api-auth/login/, including the csrftoken and sessionid.  This will be something like: csrftoken=123411231234123; sessionid=143212341234123412
2. Send the login page as a http POST using the above cookies, and setting the POST as a form with username, password, and csrfmiddlewaretoken as the form elements.
   ** The value of the csrfmiddleware should be that of the csrftoken value.

So, to re-iterate, the following must be set:

- All the original cookies must be set in the POST headers.
- The username in the POST form.
- The password in the POST form.
- The csrfmiddlewaretoken in the POST form.